# Is it the proper way to use an event bus?

Tags: android, events, otto

I am planning to add Otto event bus to decouple my communications. One of the things I want use event bus for is to communicate between a button click handler and the activity.

The idea is that the button click (from my custom view) would generate a text submission event which would notify the activity. The activity would then decide what to do with it. If the activity deems it proper, it would send the text to a service for upload or whatever.

Is this a proper way to use an event bus?

Also, what are some good practices when using event buses?

Comment: "Is this a proper way to use an event bus?" -- "proper" is highly subjective. I wouldn't use an event bus for this, as I don't see the value here over just using a listener. I use event buses for communication between components (e.g., service->activity) where loose coupling is more critical.

Comment: In general-  use them as little as possible.  They do ease some problems when what you're trying to do becomes difficult in a complex architecture because a module doesn't have all the data it needs, but its the very definition of spaghetti code.  If there's any other possible solution, use it.

Comment: Try not to (or simply - Don't) use an event bus for a `OnClickListener`. Thank me later. There is no real need to decouple a button from it's behaviour as much, but it's up to you.

Comment: I totally agree with @CommonsWare statement that "Is this a proper way" is not the way to ask questions on StackOverflow and I'll vote to close it too, but I'll weight-in with my experience. The app I work at we use 100% of user generated events going through Otto bus and I like it a lot (but you seem `like` that's subjective). Then we have different classes to handle `app navigation`, `Rest API POST` and `analytics` events. The Activity simply register/unregister those classes in the bus. Nice example that we have different handlers for logged user or guest user.

Comment: @Budius That's some good piece of advise. If you could expand on it, I'd be more than happy to accept it as an answer. Could use your experience :)

Comment: @LittleChild I just posted it. Wow that took longer to type than I hoped for. I only suggest doing stuff like this for BIG projects, small or test stuff you'll just waste time with boiler plate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still think this question should be closed as not proper for the StackOverflow model.

But for anyone looking on ***how on can organize user events around a Bus***, that's kinda of how we've done on the place I work.

Remember, that type of structure only makes sense if you're creating a big project where achieving a high level of separation makes the life of a team of developers easier. For small, quick projects or test apps that's too much effort.

PS.: all the code below is typed 100% by heart without checking any real code, so there will be typos and small errors, but should be enough to get an idea of the approach. I also didn't write any annotation like `@override`, too lazy for it.

**First**: Activity overrides `getSystemService` to supply a Bus via Context and register/unregister event handlers as needed.

```
public MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String BUS_SERVICE = "bus_service";

    private List<EventHandler> eventHandlers = new ArrayList();
    private Bus bus = new Bus();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState){
        super.onCreate(savedState);
            .... layout creation, etc, etc, etc

            if(isLoggedIn()) {
                eventHandlers.add(new LoggedUserNavigationHandler());
                eventHandlers.add(new RestPostRequestHandler());
            } else{
                eventHandlers.add(new GuestUserNavigation());
            }
            eventHandlers.add(new AnalyticsTrackingHandler());

            if(DEBUG) {
                // log all events in debug mode
                eventHandlers.add(new EventHandler(){
                             @Subscribe
                             public void onEvent(Object o){
                                 Log.d(TAG, "Event: " + o.toString);
                             }
                        });
            }

        }   
    }

    public Object getSystemService(String name){
        if(BUS_SERVICE.equals(name)) return bus;
        else return super.getSystemService(name);
    }

    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        for(int i=0, size=eventHandlers.size(); i<size; i++) {
             eventHandlers.get(i).activity = this; // pass reference, might be usefull
             bus.register(eventHandlers.get(i));
        }
    }
    public void onStop(){
        for(int i=0, size=eventHandlers.size(); i<size; i++) {
             bus.unregister(eventHandlers.get(i));
             eventHandlers.get(i).activity = null;
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

**Then**: You have all the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` (or custom widget) to be the click listener and dispatch appropriate events. For example in a ViewHolder for a photo item.

```
public class PhotoHolder extends ViewHolder implements OnClickListener {

     TextView user;
     ImageButton like;
     ImageView photo;

     Photo data; // assume this was set during `bindViewHolder`

     public PhotoHolder(View itemView) {
          super(itemView);
          user = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(...
          like = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(...
          photo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(...

          user.setOnClickListener(this);
          like.setOnClickListener(this);
          photo.setOnClickListener(this);
     }

     public void onClick(View view){
          switch(view.getId()){
              case R.id.user:
                   ((Bus)view.getSystemService(BUS_SERVICE))
                              .post(new Event.PhotoEvent.UserTap(data);
                 break;
              case R.id.like:
                   ((Bus)view.getSystemService(BUS_SERVICE))
                              .post(new Event.PhotoEvent.LikeUnlike(data);
                 break;
              case R.id.photo:
                   ((Bus)view.getSystemService(BUS_SERVICE))
                              .post(new Event.PhotoEvent.PhotoTap(data);
                 break;
          }
     }
}
```

**and the last of course**: is to create those events objects and add all the events to your appropriate handlers.

```
// add all the app events under this class, or maybe create a `Event` package and then all the events in that package
public final class Event {

    public static class PhotoEvent {
          public final Photo data;
          public Photo(Photo data){
              this.data=data;
          }

          public static class UserTap extends PhotoEvent{
                // copy matching constructor
          }

          public static class LikeUnlike extends PhotoEvent{
                // copy matching constructor
          }

          public static class PhotoTap extends PhotoEvent{
                // copy matching constructor
          }

    }
}
```

finally, handling events

```
public class RestPostRequestHandler {

     @Subscribe
     public void onPhotoLikeUnlike(Event.Photo.LikeUnlike event){
         // make your POST request here
     }
}
```

a handler for navigating:

```
public class LoggedUserNavigationHandler extends EventHandler{

     @Subscribe
     public void on(Event.Photo.UserTap event){
          Intent i = new Intent( ... create here intent for the "user profile"
          // activity reference was passed during onStart
          activity.startActivity(i);
     }
}
```

a handler for analitics:

```
 public class AnalyticsTrack {
     @Subscribe
     public void on(Event.Photo.UserTap event){
          // send event "user tap" ?
     }
 }
```

I agree with some of the comments that it's possible to create a huge, weird spaghetti code when having "tap" events going through the bus. But  if from the start a good structured approach is defined and all the developers follow it, you can achieve a project that is easy to follow and with a very clear separation of responsibilities.